# Typescript Partial Union Type

Tags: typescript, generics

I am having a hard time figuring out how to type something like this:

```js
type WithFallback<Fallback extends string, FallbackType> = {
  [fallback in Fallback]: FallbackType
} & { [rest: string]: Partial<FallbackType> };
```

So, generaly, this type takes a key `Fallback`, and its value type `FallbackType`, and creates a dictionary of a key-value pair `{[key: Fallback]: FallbackType}` and any other keys with values of type `Partial<FallbackType>`.

It should behave like a dictionary with fallback(base) values and its variations:

```js
const values = {
  base: {
    valueA: "baseA",
    valueB: "baseB",
  },
  context1: {
    valueA: "context1A",
  },
  context2: {
    valueB: "context2B",
  },
};

const useContextValues = <BaseContext extends string, BaseValuesDictionary>(
  base: BaseContext,
  values: WithFallback<BaseContext, BaseValuesDictionary>,
): BaseValuesDictionary => {
  const [activeContext, setContext] = useState<keyof typeof values>(base);

  const context = { ...values[base], ...values[activeContext] };

  return context;
};
```

This way in `base` context our values should equal `baseA` and `baseB`, in `context1` - `contest1A` and `baseB`, in `context2` - `baseA` and `context2B`.

But, when I expect `useContextValues` to return `typeof values.base` = `{valueA: string, valueB: string}`, it resolves to that:

[image]

Also, when values are passed this way, it resolved to a different type:

[image]

Can I fix it somehow? Or maybe it's not supposed to work at all?